# NonUniqueBeanException when upgrading our Grails application from 3.3.15 to 4.0.13

Tags: spring, grails, micronaut

I am trying to upgrade my Grails application from 3.3.15 to 4.0.13 (and eventually to newer versions). I am getting the following error when trying to run the application via run-app:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsWebDataBinder': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [org.grails.databinding.converters.web.LocaleAwareNumberConverter, org.grails.databinding.converters.web.LocaleAwareNumberConverter]
...
```

What I have figured out so far:

In our Grails application we extend GrailsWebDataBinder with our own class IdentifiablePropertyAwareGrailsWebDataBinder ([GrailsWebDataBinder](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v4.0.13/grails-web-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/web/databinding/GrailsWebDataBinder.groovy) is from grails-web-databinding-4.0.13). Then it is injected to replace the existing bean (I think?) via resources.groovy.

Resources.groovy

```
...
grailsWebDataBinder(IdentifiablePropertyAwareGrailsWebDataBinder, grailsApplication)
...
```

Using breakpoints inside Micronaut before the exception is thrown, it seems the issue with resolving the candidates, are Beans located in the [DefaultConvertersConfiguration.java](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v4.0.13/grails-plugin-databinding/src/main/groovy/org/grails/databinding/converters/DefaultConvertersConfiguration.java) file, which has converters for primitives/non-primitives. These seems to be autowired dependencies of grailsWebDataBinder. I believe perhaps the case sensitivity is related to the issue? For example these beans (Short vs short):

```
    @Bean("defaultShortConverter")
    protected LocaleAwareNumberConverter shortConverter() {
        final LocaleAwareNumberConverter converter = new LocaleAwareNumberConverter();
        converter.setLocaleResolver(localResolver);
        converter.setTargetType(Short.class);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean("defaultshortConverter")
    protected LocaleAwareNumberConverter primitiveShortConverter() {
        final LocaleAwareNumberConverter converter = new LocaleAwareNumberConverter();
        converter.setLocaleResolver(localResolver);
        converter.setTargetType(short.class);
        return converter;
    }
```

These beans get pulled in via grails-plugin-databinding-4.0.13.

Commenting out the resources.groovy line causes the error to go away, so I assume I must either modify resources.groovy or IdentifiablePropertyAwareGrailsWebDataBinder in some way to fix the candidate resolution. Based on the Micronaut documentation it does seem to be a case sensitivity issue. I am not sure how to solve this issue, or if my analyses is correct.